# WFFM giving error in CMS server

Tags: content-management-system, sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I am using web form for marketer. Its working fine in my local and Dev Server but in CMS environment i am getting following issue :-

```
[InvalidOperationException: folder]
   Sitecore.Form.Core.Configuration.ThemesManager.GetThemeName(Item form, ID fieldID) +434
   Sitecore.Form.Core.Configuration.ThemesManager.GetThemeUrl(Item form, Boolean deviceDependant) +250
   Sitecore.Form.Core.Configuration.ThemesManager.ScriptsTags(Item form, Item contextItem) +49
   Sitecore.Form.Core.Configuration.ThemesManager.RegisterCssScript(Page page, Item form, Item contextItem) +184
   Sitecore.Form.Web.UI.Controls.SitecoreSimpleFormAscx.OnInit(EventArgs e) +233
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +186
   System.Web.UI.Control.AddedControl(Control control, Int32 index) +189
   Sitecore.Form.Core.Renderings.FormRender.OnInit(EventArgs e) +846
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +186
   System.Web.UI.Control.AddedControl(Control control, Int32 index) +189
   Efocus.Sitecore.Renderers.SitecoreForm.AddedControl(Control control, Int32 index) +75
   Efocus.Sitecore.Renderers.SitecorePlaceholder.OnInit(EventArgs e) +554
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +186
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +291
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2098
```

Answer (score 5):

This response comes a bit late, but I just saw the same issue on a CM environment today. I hope posting this saves somebody some time in the future.

If you look at the stack trace, the exception is thrown at

```
Sitecore.Form.Core.Configuration.ThemesManager.GetThemeName(Item form, ID fieldID)
```

This method looks at the Form ID that's configured as the Forms root ID in the site definition.

```
string formsRootForSite = SiteUtils.GetFormsRootForSite(Context.Site);
Item item = form;
if (form.TemplateID != IDs.FormFolderTemplateID)
{
    item = form.Database.GetItem(formsRootForSite);
}
Assert.IsNotNull(item, "folder");
```

In my case, the configured ID did not match the actual item ID in Sitecore.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the stack trace, it seems you have configured a theme for your site that is not available in your CMS environment.

If you have a scaled instance, make sure all nodes have WFFM installed, even the content delivery servers. Instructions for Content Delivery server installation are in the WFFM administrator's documentation.

If it is not a scaled instance, you may be missing a folder on the system for the Theme that you have specified.